# SearchView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане, нужна ваша помощь. Есть проект, хочу реализовать в нем поиск. Есть одно Activity и куча Fragment, в этих фрагментах будет забиватся текст, этот текст нужно будет найти через SearchView которое находится в шапке приложения типа как у Play Market. Как реализовать данный поиск и что бы при нажатии на найденное слово, оно перекидывало на нужный фрагмент и в нужную часть текста?

Comment: Есть идейка с коленки. В каждом фрагменте можно завести ArrayList<EditText>, и соответсвенно реализуем get-метод для массива. При поиске, у фрагмента спрашиваем массив и проверяем наличие нужного текста в полях. Нужный фрагмент отображаем, если их много можно также складывать в массив и потом как нибудь отображать. Если я правильно понял задачу;)

Comment: А как сделать что бы введенное слово в SearchView сравнивалось со строками в ArrayList а потом отображал найденные результаты?

Answer (score 1):

Сам никогда такое не делал, могу лишь предположить, как это можно сделать, так что не судите строго.

Итак, первое - нам нужна линия в TextView где мы нашли необходимый текст:

```
int offset = myString.indexOf("search string");
int line = myTextView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(offset);
```

Далее - как промотать ScrollView к нужному фрагменту:
Согласно докумнтации, у ScrollView есть такой метод - scrollTo(x,y). Соответственно можно попробовать что-нибудь вроде:

```
mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mFragmentContainer.getTop() + line);
```

В общем и целом, нужно чтоб все фрагменты каким-то образом имели обратную связь с поиском. К примеру, чтоб все они реализовывали некий интерфейс, метод которого принимает искомую строку, а возвращает относительную позицию строки во фрагменте (getLineForOffset()). Далее, вышеописаным способом мы прибавляем к этому позицию самого контейнера фрагмента и прокручиваем в эту позицию наш ScrollView при помощи scrollTo.

Использован материал [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221744/scrolling-textview-in-a-scrollview-to-a-specific-substring-of-text) и [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text)